# Can't get a substring and then trim a variable

Tags: c#

I am getting errors with the following:

```
var a = id.Substring(0,8).TrimEnd("0").Length
```

What I want to do is to take my string called id. Trucate it to eight characters and then check the length after taking away trailing "0".

The error message is:

```
Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'string.TrimEnd(params char[])' has some invalid arguments
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing is wrong because you're passing the `.TrimEnd()` method a string, instead of a `char[]` [as the documentation mentions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx).

You need something like:

```
var a = id.Substring(0,8).TrimEnd(new char[]{'0'}).Length;
```

You can even pass in a single quoted character to make things more readable.

```
var a = id.Substring(0,8).TrimEnd('0').Length;
```

Comment: Note that the explicit array isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: There's no need to explicitly create the `char[]` - it's a params array parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the `Substring` call. This won't work either:

```
// Broken
"foo".TrimEnd("0");
```

Look at the compiler error message - this will work:

```
"foo".TrimEnd('0');
```

If you're concerned about micro-optimization, you *might* want to avoid creating a new array on each invocation:

```
private static readonly char[] ZeroForTrimming = {'0'};

...

var a = id.Substring(0,8).TrimEnd(ZeroForTrimming).Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try single quotes around the 0:

```
var a = id.Substring(0, 8).TrimEnd('0').Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

exactly what it says, the method wants a char[] not a string. You could most easily write

```
var a = id.Substring(0,8).TrimEnd("0".ToCharArray()).Length;
```

I added the ToCharArray in because, sometimes you may want the string to be variable.

Be aware, unless you are certain that that string will ALWAYS be at least 8 characters long, you are asking for trouble. You need to verify that the string at least as long as the 2nd argument for Substring, or you will most likely be throwing index out of range exceptions at random times.

Answer (score 0):

The method signature shows that it requires any number of `char`'s. You have provided a `string`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) for the documentation of the method.

Instead, you need something like:

```
var a = id.Substring(0, 8).TrimEnd('0').Length
```

Note the single quotes around the character.

Answer (score 0):

`TrimEnd` expects a char array, not a string. A char literal is written as `'x'` by using single quotes.

```
var a = id.Substring(0,8).TrimEnd('0').Length;
```

Since the parameter of `TrimEnd` is marked with the `params` keyword, you have two possibilities to pass parameters:

```
s.TrimEnd(new char[]{'0',' ',';'})
```

or

```
s.TrimEnd('0',' ',';')
```

In your case, this suffices:

```
s.TrimEnd('0')
```